# Objective-C How to get data (strings, integers, doubles, etc.) from UITextFields with a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, math, uitextfield

How can I, in objective-c, access the data that the user has input from textfields with an action method connected to a button?
For Example, User inputs in to textfield wage, 9, inputs into textfield hours, 10, the button would take wage (9) and times it by hours (10) and print in textfield payCheck, 90. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *text = [UITextField text];
```

You can get the value from textfield by the property 'text'

Then convert the type you want, for example int value,

```
int intValue = [text intValue];
```

So in the function that handle your button clicked, get those value and assign it to another textField using

```
[UITextField setText:text];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use componentSeperated by function for string. so in your case you can get 9 and 10 and then you can multiply it and can get 90.

Answer (score 0):

You could place 3 text boxes up, one for wage, one for hours and one for the output pay check. As the user types in the wages and/or hours the pay is shown in the pay check text box. Here's a coded example:

Here's the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TestViewController;

@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    TestViewController *viewController;

    UITextField *txtWage;
    UITextField *txtHours;
    UITextView *txtPay;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TestViewController *viewController;

-(void)calculatePay;

@end
```

and the .m file:

```
#import "TestAppDelegate.h"
#import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation TestAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // wage
    txtWage = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 50.0, 25.0)] autorelease];
    txtWage.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    txtWage.placeholder = @"wage";
    [viewController.view addSubview:txtWage];

    // hours
    txtHours = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 10.0, 50.0, 25.0)] autorelease];
    txtHours.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    txtHours.placeholder = @"hours";
    [viewController.view addSubview:txtHours];

    // payCheck
    txtPay = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150.0, 10.0, 50.0, 25.0)] autorelease];
    txtPay.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    txtPay.editable = NO;
    [viewController.view addSubview:txtPay];

    // list for changes to wage and hours
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(calculatePay)
                                                 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // have keyboard show up in wage box
    [txtWage becomeFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Free up as much memory as possible by purging cached data objects that can be recreated (or reloaded from disk) later.
     */
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [txtWage release];
    [txtHours release];
    [txtPay release];
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Other Methods

-(void)calculatePay {
    NSLog(@"calulating pay");
    txtPay.text = @"";
    if (txtWage.text.length > 0 && [txtWage.text intValue]>0 
        && txtHours.text.length > 0 && [txtHours.text intValue]>0 
        ) 
    {
        int pay = [txtWage.text intValue] * [txtHours.text intValue];
        txtPay.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:pay] stringValue];
    }
}


@end
```